# group rows that have the same equivalent value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the next sample data into a table (EQUCODES), the column "CODE" has a equivalent value, which is represented into "EQCODE" column. This value in the "EQCODE" column can be another record with same value in "CODE" column and the equivalent value will have the vice versa value i.e.

```
ID  || CODE || EQCODE  
--------------------------
1   ||  a   || b   
2   ||  b   || a   
3   ||  c   || d   
4   ||  d   || c
```

other table (CLIENTTYPE) that I want to join with above table has next estructure,

```
CLIENTID  || CODE   
--------------------------
1         ||  a  
2         ||  a    
3         ||  b   
4         ||  a   
6         ||  b   
7         ||  b
```

How can I group these CLIENTTYPE records in such a way the query return a single record because they are equivalents once they are joined with the EQUCODES table?

Comment: If these are the two input tables you want to join please provide output data.

Answer (score 0):

To find the canonical code for each client, use this:

```
select ClientID, min(code) as Code
from (
    select ClientID, EQUCODES.EQCode as Code
    from CLIENTTYPE inner join EQUCODES on CLIENTTYPE.Code = EQUCODES.Code
  Union
    select ClientID, EQUCODES.Code
    from CLIENTTYPE inner join EQUCODES on CLIENTTYPE.Code = EQUCODES.EQCode
) U
Group By ClientID
```

If you then want to aggregate by `code`, you could wrap that query in this:

```
select Code, count(ClientID) from
( -- the query above
) G
Group by Code
```